# How can I get the last seven days in dutch language using PHP

Tags: php, loops, date, locale, translation

I am trying to get the last 7 days of the week in Dutch. Getting the last 7 days by itself is no issue, I do it like this:

```
function getLastNDays($days, $format = 'd/m'){
    $m = date("m"); $de= date("d"); $y= date("Y");
    $dateArray = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$days-1; $i++){
        $dateArray[] = '' . date($format, mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-$i),$y)) . '';
    }
    return array_reverse($dateArray);
}

$arr = getLastNDays(7, 'Y-m-d');
```

When I loop over `$arr` and put the results in `$day` this is what each `$day` looks like:

```
2019-09-19
2019-09-20
2019-09-21
2019-09-22
2019-09-23
2019-09-24
2019-09-25
```

So to get it in the abbreviated version, inside my loop I do:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $day);
$dag = $date->format("D");
```

Which gives me:

```
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
Tue
Wed
```

Now to translate it to Dutch I found out I can first use `setlocale` and then `strftime` so now my entire code looks like this:

```
function getLastNDays($days, $format = 'd/m'){
    $m = date("m"); $de= date("d"); $y= date("Y");
    $dateArray = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$days-1; $i++){
        $dateArray[] = '' . date($format, mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-$i),$y)) . '';
    }
    return array_reverse($dateArray);
}

$arr = getLastNDays(7, 'Y-m-d');
foreach($arr as $day) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $day);
    $dag = $date->format("D");
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');
    $dagnl = strftime('%a', $date);
    echo $dagnl . "<br>";
}
```

But this gives me just 7 empty lines (because the 
 is echoed). Why is it not working?

Comment: You have to pass a `int` timestamp and not a `DateTime` object to [`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a timestamp to `strftime`, not a date :

```
$dagnl = strftime('%a', $date->getTimestamp());
```

Output :

> do
>
> vr
>
> za
>
> zo
>
> ma
>
> di
>
> wo

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't utilize PHP library but its a workaround.

You can try something like

```
$weekday_dutch = array(
    "Sun" => "Zondag",
    "Mon" => "Maandag",
    "Tue" => "Dinsdag",
    "Wed" => "Woensdag",
    "Thu" => "Donderdag",
    "Fri" => "Vrijdag",
    "Sat" => "Zaterdag",
);
```

And just use English names to convert to Dutch with

```
$weekday_dutch["Sun"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed a `DateTime` object to the `strftime`, instead of an integer.

> `$dagnl = strftime('%a', $date);`

But why all this complexity! You can get the last 7 days using only 2 lines of code:

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');

for($i=7;$i>0;$i--)
    echo strftime('%a', strtotime("-{$i} days")) . "<br>";
```

Output:

```
wo
do
vr
za
zo
ma
di
```